# Can't bind to 'matRowDefColumns' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-template

I am testing an Angular 7 component which uses `mat-table`, and I have defined a mock module, which declares and exports a mock `mat-row` component as such:

```
@Component({selector: 'mat-row', template: ''}) export class StubMatRowComponent {
  @Input() public matRowDefColumns: string[];
}
```

The usage in the template is this:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let foo; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

With this syntax, the error I get is "Can't bind to 'matRowDefColumns' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'."

If I didn't need `foo`, I could write this as follows, which would work:

```
<mat-row matRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-row>
```

Does anyone know how I can get my mock to work using template syntax?

As a side note, obviously an alternative is rather than importing my mock module, I could import the real thing, but just as obviously, for testing purposes I prefer mocks rather than full integrations.

Comment: it's not `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>` ? (see that it a tag "tr"). BTW check if the module witch you declare your component import the MatTableModule, see a stackblitz example that it's equal than the basic example but the component it's in a new module https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-up8red?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnew-module.ts (see that if you don't import the MatModule in new-module.ts an error happens)

Comment: If that is valid, I would need to alter my entire template, because per the living standard, `<tr>` is only valid within table elements https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-tr-element. Regardless, that is unlikely to work because it uses the same syntax, and my last paragraph addresses why I prefer not to import MatTableModule directly. If I can't find a solution for my mock, I can however fall back to a full integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that because `matRowDef` is a *structural directive*, not a property to be bound, a mock structural directive must be created and imported:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[matRowDef]'
}) export class StubMatRowDefDirective {
  @Input() matRowDefColumns: string[];
}
```